# Mysql PHP Select with multiple values, MAX(LENGTH())

Tags: mysql, filtering

hello friends i am working on a query to get a list of registry, but i need get duplicate entries, and preserve only that have more length

Example table:

```
ID     = INT Auto increment
IDref  = INT not null
UserId = INT ZeroFill

+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| ID     | IDref   | UserId |         |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       | 00001  |         |
| 3      | 1       | 001    |         |
| 4      | 1       | 002    |         |
| 5      | 2       | 00001  |         |
| 6      | 2       | 001    |         |
| 7      | 2       | 002    |         |
| 8      | 3       | 00001  |         |
| 9      | 4       | 002    |         |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

The Query

```
SELECT ID, IDref, UserId 
FROM Table 
WHERE UserId = '00001' OR '002' 
GROUP BY IDref 
HAVING count(IDref) > 0 
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(UserId ) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**Update**
I am Geting

```
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| ID     | IDref   | UserId |         |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 4      | 1       | 002    |         |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

i required this output:

```
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| ID     | IDref   | UserId |         |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       | 00001  |         |
| 5      | 2       | 00001  |         |
| 8      | 3       | 00001  |         |
| 9      | 4       | 002    |         |//count(IDref) > 0// one registry find.
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

But not work my Query. someone can help me plz.

Last Update with working code Thank Barmar:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.IDref, t1.UserId
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT IDref, MAX(LENGTH(UserId)) AS maxlength
      FROM Table1
      WHERE UserID IN ('00001', '002')
      GROUP BY IDref) AS t2
ON t1.IDref = t2.IDref AND LENGTH(t1.UserId) = t2.maxlength
WHERE t1.UserId IN ('00001', '002')
```

**ok , but may you see the performance of this query in a table with 20,000 records will be faster?**

Comment: what results/query are you getting though?

Comment: all time get the UserId short registry .... all 002

Comment: i have update this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE UserId = '00001' OR '002'
```

is not the correct way to test if a column matches either of these values. The correct way is

```
WHERE UserId IN ('00001', '002')
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
WHERE (UserId = '00001') OR '002'
```

which is always true because `'002'` is not false.

You also should remove `LIMIT 1`. Otherwise, you only get one of the `IDRef` that has duplicates.

`ORDER BY LENGTH(UserId)` doesn't make the grouped value select the row with the longest length -- ordering is done **after** grouping, and grouping just selects one of the values arbitrarily. For that, you need to use one of the techniques in [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1)

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.IDref, t1.UserId
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT IDref, MAX(LENGTH(UserId)) AS maxlength
      FROM Table1
      WHERE UserID IN ('00001', '002')
      GROUP BY IDref) AS t2
ON t1.IDref = t2.IDref AND LENGTH(t1.UserId) = t2.maxlength
WHERE t1.UserId IN ('00001', '002')
```

There's no need for `HAVING COUNT(IDRef) > 0`, because count is always more than 0.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac210/3)

Comment: if of course you're right , the problem is with the "Where IN" and the filter of duplicates and the length characters . becouse it continue showing, 
because the result is still showing me the less string and not the larger

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to get the longest user ID.

Comment: i get this error: Unknown column 't2.IDref' in 'on clause'

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that error, but I did have some other problems that I've fixed. See the new code.

Comment: this work but 
ok , but may you see the performance of this query in a table with 20,000 records will be faster?

Comment: Unfortunately, `LENGTH()` can't use an index, so this query will be slow. I don't think there's any way to do faster, though.